# Passing reference types by ref - Flex/Actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I know that in C# when you pass an object (non primitive) to a method the following is true:

1. A reference to the object is passed
2. Changes made to the object in the method are reflected outside of the method.

Also, you can pass a reference to a reference in C# e.g **this.changeObject(ref myObject);**, in which case:

- Changes to the object and also to the ref are reflected outside of the method e.g. **myObject = new new List();** would change the passed objects referred location.

My question:

Is this possible to do in Flex/Actionscript - can a ref keyword be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot. ActionScript doesn't have a `ref` keyword or a similar (double pointer like) concept. You always pass object references to functions (except for primitives) and modifications are reflected back.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at the documentation again, and could find nothing. Thanks for the reply